# Hide iOS Keyboard, but allow user to move cursor around

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'd like to allow a user to move the cursor around a uitextarea by tapping as they normally can do, but I don't want the keyboard to show.

Is there a method I can override to make this possible?

Comment: use uitextview for this.

Answer (score 1):

If your don't want to show keyboard and cursor then just `return NO`, at end of

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    /// Your stuff; 
    return NO;
}
```

**Another Option:**

```
UIView* dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
myTextField.inputView = dummyView;
```

Add `UIView` *(dummyView)* to your `UITextField`'s `inputView`.

This will not return KeyBoard but also display blinking cursor.

Comment: I am able to place a cursor with the code mentioned above. I also need to edit the text at the position where the cursor is placed. But I cannot edit the text at the place where the cursor is placed. Your help will be appreciated!!